# notepad++ User Defined Language regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, language

Is there a way to recognize certain text as a keyword Only if it is the first text in the row?

I don't see such an option within the 'User Defined Language' -> 'Keywords Lists' options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible. You can consult [UDL2 documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/index.html) to learn about User Defined Language capabilities. It is intentionally restricted in order to be easy enough giving a compromise between usability for ordinary users and efficiency.

**Solution:** The only thing I can advise to you beyond UDL2 is to create your own build of Notepad++. If you get the source, you can see that all built-in language highlighters are implemented procedurally using `.lex` files. You can create yours and there you have unlimited highlighting possibilities. Then you need to add color definitions to existing XML files, menu item and necessary bindings and you should be done. Hint: built-in **Batch** language is already highlighting first word on the line so maybe it is a good point to start from.

**Workaround:** if highlighting of first word on line is sufficient to you, just switch langugage to **Batch**. :)

**Another solution:** In these cases, user RProgram always suggests people to switch from Notepad++ to [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) editor. Its user-defined languages have much wider capabilities. Maybe this will be the fastest way how you can get to desired result without going too deep.

Comment: thanks miroxlav.  Yes, i had been looking at the UDL2 documentation and was hoping I just overlooked that section of the documentation.  I put a bounty on the same question over in stack overflow, "notepad++ keyword only if at beginning of line".  If you put the same answer over there you can have the bounty.

Comment: @Fractal - I have enhanced the answer for you.

Comment: thanks for the additional information.  According to stack overflow I have to wait two hours to give the 50 points for some reason.

Comment: @Fractal - sure, I know that too... [SO] engine wants to give time to others to possibly beat the best answer. No problem. In the meantime, I have checked SynWrite. (It is not needed to install it, just unzip.) Menu **Options** > **Customize lexers library...** > icon **New** will take you into UDL definition environment. What I could see, the possibilities are huge, but difficulty is high, too (as always, these things go hand in hand).

Comment: Thanks miroxlav.  I appreciate all the advice.  It helped out a lot. :)

Comment: Hi. Do you know if the same restriction applies to code-folding openers? The language I am working in, Stata, supports blocks of the form `input..end`, but my coworkers like to use "input" in the middle of a line (like as a variable name), so I have to turn off my ability to fold such blocks, as it is now. Thanks. (I figure the answer is again "no" and wasn't worth a separate question.)